# Why doesn't vue update data after nexttick?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to learn about vuejs nexttick methods and I'm not sure why message isn't being updated after nexttick in this example..

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'one'
  },
  created() {
    this.message = 'two';
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.message = 'three';
    });
    this.message = 'four'
  }
})
```

If I echo it using

```
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

I only see `three`. I understand after why one and two are showng because nexttick() changes the data rapidly, but why is `four` not shown instead?

Answer (score 3):

When you call `$nextTick()`, it schedules the inner function to be run in the next tick. However, the function that is *calling* `$nextTick()` will complete before the function passed into `nextTick()` will be called.

Here is the offical documenation for `$nextTick()` https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick

> Defer the callback to be executed after the next DOM update cycle. Use
> it immediately after you’ve changed some data to wait for the DOM
> update. This is the same as the global Vue.nextTick, except that the
> callback’s this context is automatically bound to the instance calling
> this method.

`this.message = 'three';` is getting executed last, which is why you always see "three"

Your code actually executes in the following order:

```
this.message = 'two';
this.message = 'four'
//then in the next tick of the event loop / DOM update which is likely instantaneous
this.message = 'three';
```

The order of your code in your file does not determine the order in which it is actually executed by the javascript engine.

Comment: so nexttick is run last? if that is the case, why cant I see 'four' before 'three'

Comment: Because it happens instantaneously. It is so fast that you only see 'three'

Comment: To demonstrate this, replace `$nextTick()` with `setTimeout()` with varying times. Try 5000ms, 1000ms, 100ms, 10ms and 1ms. `$nextTick()` is roughly equivalent to `setTimeout(fn, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

According to your question about

> but why is four not shown instead?

it's about macrotask microtask problem. when you use nextTick, maybe your browser support promise, so Vue will use it to execute your function.

And because of promise will be classified to microtask, your nextTick function actually done before UI Render.

setTimeout is classified to macrotask, your function will be done at the next event loop after UI Render, you will see 'four' for a short time!!

**DOM updated not equal to UI Render**